# Customer Portal Self registration and User trigger

Tags: trigger, customer-portal, user-record, triggercontext

Will trigger (before insert) on User object fire when a customer portal user registers using customer portal self registration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will fire! After all its a trigger and it will fire based on the DML events that are added in the Trigger.

Self Registration is a KIND of DML (INSERT) and hence your Before Insert trigger will fire.